# K&R Chapter 1.5.4: "How would you test the word count program?"

Tags: c, io

Beginner here.

In the ANSI C textbook by K&R, page 20, they ask: How would you test the word count program?

I have copied exactly from the text book, using the CodeBlocks IDE, console application. I have seen many great input tests online, but my question is even dumber. How do I actually input something? Nothing happens when I press enter. Do I have this problem because I am using an IDE and therefore not learning how to run C programs properly?
Thanks in advance. [I added a picture to show you what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQQzg.png)

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1    /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0   /* outside a word */

/* counts lines, words and characters as input */

main()
{
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

    state = OUT;
    /* set these three constants to 0: */
    nl = nw = nc = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
            /* || == OR (&& == AND)
            evaluation of the following line
            will stop as soon as the truth or
            falsehood is known, so the order matters */
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' == c == '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT){
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

Comment: Post code as code formatted text, not as pictures. I can't compile your picture.

Comment: You're right. I added the code to the original post

Comment: Although K&R is a great book, it is extremely dated.  In particular, use `int main(void)`

Comment: Short answer, "yes".  Don't use an IDE in the beginning.  To provide input, just redirect in a shell.  eg `cc prog.c && ./a.out < input-file`

Comment: I'll get right on that, thank you very much

Comment: The word count program doesn't count words at each input line, it does it internally until  you mark the input end (in windows you can by pressing Ctrl-Z and then Return)  Better if you run the program on a MS-DOS window. K&R examples are made to use a normal terminal (a unix terminal) so you have to move to such kind of environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program to count words in K&R 2nd edition is made to run on an environment in which you signal the end of input somehow.  Normally, as they used UNIX all the time, they used Ctrl-D sequence (which is valid if you run the program in Linux or any Unix-like operating system)  This has been so since the early beginning of the UNIX system.

Windows signals the end of input in a console application by the input of a Ctrl-Z (probably followed by a keyboard return key)

If you redirect the input from a file (as when you say `a.out <my_input_file.txt`) you'll get the number of words at the end, when there's no more input in the file.

You are running the program in an IDE, which is something that normally hides you where standard input and standard output go, or how to signal the window you show how to say that there's not more input to the program.

For the program to get to it's end, you have first to know how to get to an end on input.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS:

```
gcc kr_wc.c -o kr_wc
./kr_wc < example_text.txt
```

Example output:

```
40 260 1397
```

Where example_text.txt is this file:

```
1.5.4 Word Counting

The fourth in our series of useful programs counts lines, words, and
characters, with the loose definition that a word is any sequence of
characters that does not contain a blank, tab or newline. This is a
bare-bones version of the UNIX program wc.

#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1 /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0 /* outside a word */
/* count lines, words, and characters in input */
int main() {
  int c, nl, nw, nc, state;
  state = OUT;
  nl = nw = nc = 0;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    ++nc;
    if (c == '\n')
      ++nl;
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
      state = OUT;
    else if (state == OUT) {
      state = IN;
      ++nw;
    }
  }
  printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}

Every time the program encounters the first character of a word, it
counts one more word. The variable state records whether the program
is currently in a word or not; initially it is "not in a word", which
is assigned the value OUT. We prefer the symbolic constants IN and
OUT to the literal values 1 and 0 because they make the program more
readable. In a program as tiny as this, it makes little difference,
but in larger programs, the increase in clarity is well worth the
modest extra effort to write it this way from the beginning. You'll
also find that it's easier to make extensive changes in programs
where magic numbers appear only as symbolic constants.
```

Answer (score 0):

The examples in K&R omit a return type of main, which is not valid in modern C, so add `int` before `main()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1    /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0   /* outside a word */

/* counts lines, words and characters as input */

int main()
{
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

    state = OUT;
    /* set these three constants to 0: */
    nl = nw = nc = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
            /* || == OR (&& == AND)
            evaluation of the following line
            will stop as soon as the truth or
            falsehood is known, so the order matters */
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' == c == '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT){
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

> "*How do I actually input something? Nothing happens when I press enter.*"

If you got problems with your IDE just run it [online](https://onlinegdb.com/HyXXq6dv8).

> "*How would you test the word count program*"?

To cite the authors of a bundle of K&R solutions with an answer to that particular question [here](https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_1:Exercise_11):

> It sounds like they are really trying to get the programmers to learn how to do a unit test. I would submit the following:
>
> 1. input file contains zero words
> 2. input file contains 1 enormous word without any newlines
> 3. input file contains all white space without newlines
> 4. input file contains 66000 newlines
> 5. input file contains word/{huge sequence of whitespace of different >kinds}/word
> 6. input file contains 66000 single letter words, 66 to the line
> 7. input file contains 66000 words without any newlines
> 8. input file is /usr/dict contents (or equivalent)
> 9. input file is full collection of moby words
> 10. input file is binary (e.g. its own executable)
> 11. input file is /dev/null (or equivalent)
>
> 66000 is chosen to check for integral overflow on small integer machines.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answer. I must read up on unite tests.

I actually installed Windows Subsystem for Linux, compiled and ran my (edited) code there with the same result. My guess is that the code works perfectly, but there is nothing in this code that will exit the while loop.

Comment: @AsgerSkovVelling Yes, that´s right. You have to input `EOF` by the keyboard - its not a real "end of file" in its manner but that is how things are build up. I think `EOF` must be done by the shortcut `CTRL+Z` on Windows. You can also take a look on `MinG for Windows` which brings you Linux`s gcc on Windows. I´ve installed that one.

Comment: Not returning in main is permitted by the standard, although not recommended, because of legacy code still running outside.